# Adding Hyperlink to text in JQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, innertext

I am using innerText to add text to my object. Is there an easy way to add a hyperlink to the text? 'trend' also has a attribute called 'link'.

```
this.node.innerText = trend.get('value');
```

Comment: Can't you just use innerHTML instead? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add a DOM element using jQuery's wrap():

`$(this).wrap('<a href="..." />')`;

Answer (score 15):

Use `**WRAP**` function

```
  $(someSelector).wrap(function() {
       var link = $('<a/>');
       link.attr('href', 'somewhere_far_far_away');
       link.text($(this).text());
       return link;
    });
```